# Tika exception error while indexing rich documents rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot-solr, apache-tika

Well I am just implementing full text search in rich documents using sunspot_cell.
I am using paperclip for attachment.

I have done all the required configurations and include all the *.jar files in solr/lib dir.
But its not able index the document. **I am getting the following Tika exception error:**

```
RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error:     org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser@17fc44f
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser@17fc44f
    at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:219)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1372)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
```

**My Gemfile looks like**:

```
gem 'sunspot', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git"
gem 'sunspot_rails', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", :require =>  "sunspot_rails"
gem 'sunspot_test'
gem 'sunspot_cell', :git => 'git://github.com/zheileman/sunspot_cell.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sunspot_cell_jars', :git => 'https://github.com/mrcsparker/sunspot_cell_jars.git'
  gem 'sunspot_solr', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", :require => "sunspot_solr"
  gem 'progress_bar'
end
```

Any solutions to this.

Regards,
Karan

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems to be illogical but somehow i was able to find the solution to this.

Just try to run your development server using Web-rick instead of any other eg:thin
It will start working.:)